# How to Convert Positive or Negative Scientific Notation to Number in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, data-conversion, scientific-notation

I have tried this two codes:

1)

```
Decimal h2 = 0;
Decimal.TryParse("-8.13E-06", out h2);
```

2)

```
Decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString(used[row, column].Value), NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

But It is not working for **-8.13E-06** Value.

Any other better option to convert Scientific Notation to Decimal?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "not working"? do you get an error, or an unexpected value?

Comment: In first Code I'm getting 0;

Comment: and in second Code I'm getting Error as Incorrect Input string

Comment: When using a `TryParse` method you really should capture the `bool` result or use it in an `if` statement so you can handle the case where it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your culture uses "." as separator:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("-8.13E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

Or you can specify the `InvariantCulture`:

```
decimal d = Decimal.Parse("-8.13E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or as in your exapmple:

```
Decimal h2 = 0;
Decimal.TryParse("-8.13E-06", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out h2);
```

Comment: `decimal d = Decimal.Parse("-8.13E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
It worked well Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

AllowExponent wont work as per this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx

> Indicates that the numeric string can be in exponential notation. The AllowExponent flag allows the parsed string to contain an exponent
>   that begins with the "E" or "e" character and that is followed by an
>   optional positive or negative sign and an integer. In other words, it
>   successfully parses strings in the form nnnExx, nnnE+xx, and nnnE-xx.
>   It does not allow a decimal separator or sign in the significand or
>   mantissa; to allow these elements in the string to be parsed, use the
>   AllowDecimalPoint and AllowLeadingSign flags, or use a composite style
>   that includes these individual flags.

System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float is such a composite style